# Using C++ STL without copying data

Tags: c++, opencv, stl, queue

I am using Opencv Mat container to read frames from video steam. I need both current and previous frames.

For now I am copying the current  frame to the previous frame at the end of each iteration. Is it possible to avoid this **deep** copy using one of the STL containers?

```
std::string VidPath;
VideoCapture VidStream;
cv::Mat Prev,Curr;

if (!VidStream.open(VidPath))
{
    cout << "Cant open video" << endl;
    return 1;
}

VidStream.read(Prev);

while(VidStream.read(Curr))
{
   //do some operations between Curr and Prev 
   Curr.copyTo(Prev)// is it possible to avoid this copy?
}
```

Comment: You can use move assignment, there is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/12613436/4243624

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is called swapping.

One option would be to hold two pointers in your class. One is for the current frame and one for the previous frame.
When you are done processing your current frame, just swap the pointers and start working on the next frame again (which then can override the current frame).

An other option would be to use two `std::vector` which provide the [`swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap) method, which means no copying.
Other Container like `std::list` or `std::dequeu` also provide the `swap` method.

You may find additional information when searching for double buffering, which is a technique for flicker free content displaying.

Comment: There is even `std::swap` function which swaps the content of two objects if their class meets some requirements.